# Display folder that is being searched

Tags: bash, grep

Is there any way to display a current folder/file that is being searched while `grep -r` is performing? That would give me a sense of how much work is already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find -type f -print -exec grep foo {} +
```

PS: To separate search results from normal output, you may use this:

```
find -type f -print -exec bash -c 'grep class "${@}" | tee -a result.txt' -- {} +
```

In addition to get printed on screen - along with the filenames, the search results will be stored in `result.txt`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Just prints out all the folder names rapidly and stops. Also I can't quite get what "{} +" means.

Comment: Yeah, I read it, still don't get it. Anyway, adding -a to grep and replacing "+" with "\;" did the job.

Comment: @tyrande Looks like your `find` doesn't support the `+`. It would speed up things a bit. If `\;` works for you, then use that. If you need `grep -a`, then yes, use it. You didn't mention that in your question. Besides the command works for you, right?

Comment: I checked it again and `+` does work, though it prints all the folders first and then does the search, so I can't use it as a progress indicator. Otherwise, yes, it works.

Comment: If you want `find` to do it one by one, then use `\;` instead of `+`. But that would be slightly slower.

Comment: @tyrande note once again that the tool to find files is named `find`, not `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run *grep* under *strace* to obtain all *open* system calls. An invocation of *sed* can then select the calls that open directories and print the directory name. I've redirected the printing of the directory names to the standard error, so that it will not interfere with *grep*'s normal output.

```
strace -o >(sed -n 's/^openat([^,]*, "\([^"]*\)".*O_DIRECTORY.*/\1/p' 1>&2) -s 1024 -e trace=openat grep -r foo .
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I figure out how it works. Looks way too complicated for me atm.

Comment: The strace program spies on the operations of grep and the sed program prints out the names of opened directories.

Comment: This is obviously painfully slow. Plus it will print all system calls, not the files grep is searching through.

Comment: @hek2mgl "Painfully slow" is a subjective matter. The invocation is about 10X slower than plain grep. The ` -e trace=openat` argument and the *sed* filter ensure that only the *open* system calls are captured and only those that refer to directories are displayed.

Comment: Aha. And attaching strace to the running process and filtering with sed comes for free?